# Renaming files with Visual Studio and TortoiseSVN

Tags: visual-studio, tortoisesvn

I am using Visual Studio for editing source code and once a while I switch to Windows Explorer to commit changes with TortoiseSVN. This procedure works well for me and I am quite happy with it. However, recently I started to rename classes and reorganize namespaces a lot. I like to rename and move files in Visual Studio because it automatically update the project file for me. When I commit changes, however, I have to tell TortoiseSVN that old files were deleted and new files were added, which isn't quite true and it breaks the history of the particular code.

So my question is: **When I rename file in Visual Studio, is there any way to tell TortoiseSVN that I did that to preserve file history?**

---

**Update (16:30):**
Ankhsvn seems to be obvious answer but I like thing as they are now. It sounds weird but I like TortoiseSVN not being integrated in Visual Studio. This is maybe because of my two monitor setup when I have always opened file manager on my secondary monitor. Maybe because I found Solution Explorer a little clunky. Maybe because I like to think about code editing and revision control as separate steps of software development. I don't know.

Comment: Seems that AnkhSVN is your answer, as almost all answers mention it, including mine :-)

Comment: Jakub, I'm with you on that. I have tried numerous CVS and SVN plugins for VS and always went back to Tortoise.

Comment: +1 for great question. Also +1 if I could, for wanting a solution that doesn't require a plug-in. Whilst AnkhSVN is way better than it used to be, it is still no substitute for TSVN. In my experience working without AnkhSVN has been more productive than working with it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have a newer version of TSVN (after 1.5.0, I think), you can use the "[repair moves](http://tortoisesvn.net/repairmoves.html)" feature. I use it all the time for situations just like that.

Comment: You saved my history. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, I have used this feature so much to get around renaming in VS. It is just so much work though, so I'll try AnkhSVN. Just a thought I had the other day... Imagine if TSVN had a Suggest renames feature in the commit dialogue. That would be epic and a massive time saver!!!

Comment: Thank you Jeff, you made my day!

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/. It looks for these things and handles the changes appropriately and shows you directly in the Solution Explorer what has changed. Plus, you don't have to go back to Explorer! I really like it a lot!

There is no reason to prevent file history. That is the whole point of a source code control system.

Comment: But better you switch to this :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) will do the job.
It's a free SVN plugin for Visual Studio.
There is another one - [VisualSVN](http://visualsvn.com/), but its shareware.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use ***ankhsvn*** plugin for visual studio for svn

or there are plugins like that

Answer (score 0):

No. You should do all file moving/renaming in TortoiseSVN (ie file explorer).

There are SVN plugins for Visual Studio that might do what you want.

Comment: Exactly. First, rename a file so that it has changed name, then replace it with with newer one, then commit. In this case SVN will now that 2 operations had been done.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, when you use TortoiseSVN to rename your files within the boundaries of source control it deletes and adds the renamed files as new, too.

[See here:](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html)

> **Commit the parent folder**
>
> Since renames and moves are done as a
>   delete followed by an add [...]

Comment: Actually it's done as a copy-and-delete. That way SVN preserves (copies) the history.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can do what you asked, but I think you can solve your problems if you start using [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/).

It's a great tool that integrates Subversion into Visual Studio and you can do your commits from the VS IDE.